# Force calculation with a fulcrum not working out

Tags: forces

I hope this "applied" question can be asked here (and forgive my naivety in physics for the simple question). I've built the following murphy bunk bed:

[image: Open Position of Murphy Bunk Bed]

It rotates around the circles (the fulcrum) into a closed position:

[image: Closed Position of Murphy Bunk Bed]

I decided to buy gas springs (the retracting kind) to assist in closing the bed. Using the measurements from the picture,

[image: Measurements to compute force]

from what I understand, the calculation would be:

force = 110*(35.8125)/11.4375 = 344.43

At this point, I was feeling pretty savvy and bought two springs that had 150 lbs of force, thinking this would be perfect. But I had a problem--instead of naturally falling open as I expected, it required all 200 pounds of me at the edge of the bed to get it to budge.

So where am I going wrong? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I migrated this to DIY (http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/44150/computing-force-with-a-fulcrum-on-a-murphy-bed).

Answer (score 0):

Is the "110 pounds of force required to lift" the weight of the shelf?  If it is, then you have to apply its force at the center of gravity, which would not be 35 13/16" away from the fulcrum, but somewhere around 17" to 18" (depending on the distance from the fulcrum to the other edge of the bed, which affects where the center is).  If not, then where did the 110 pounds come from?

Comment: Not quite. I used a lift scale at the end of the bed to measure the weight as I put it in the closed position.

Answer (score 0):

As the spring is not vertical, its torque is reduced by a factor $\cos \theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle from the vertical.  This should make the bed harder to close, which sounds like it is not your problem.  When the bed is closed, it looks like all the weight is inboard of the pivot.  You don't have any weight helping you extend the springs.

Comment: Probably should also explain that a gas spring exerts a fixed force independent of extension, not like a coil spring.

Comment: Agreed...not the problem I'm having. It seems my bed is defying physics! :)

Comment: Is your problem starting to open it?  Or getting it the last bit of the way open?

Comment: @RossMillikan--both. It's difficult throughout the range.